# Update Device SDK Android

Tags: android, updates

My phone is running an earlier version of the Android SDK and I would like to update it.  Is this possible?

I can easily update the version on my computer with the SDK manager, but if I target the newer version I get the error `deviceSDK < minSDK`.

Is there a way to update the actual device sdk?  I can't seem find any mention of this on the internet.

Comment: @Budius then what causes the error deviceSDK < minSDK.  If not the SDK per se, is there some system update that I can run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the Android version that you are running on the phone is an older version than what is specified in the Gradle for Minsdkversion.
Android 4.4.2(Kit Kat) is sdk version 19 where as 6.0.1(Marshmallow) is sdk 23.

The only way is to wait for a manufacture update or to root the device and install a custom ROM that is a newer base version of Android.